2024: chrome not reachable python selenium
I want to open a Chrome window with my settings and connect to it via Selenium.
I start Chrome then try to connect but I get this error:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome 
at localhost:9014 from chrome not reachable.

This is the code.
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()      
os.system('2024\\startchrome_dev.bat')

options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9014")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

Chrome starts but Selenium is unable to reach it.
The content of startchrome_dev.bat is as follows.
"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"  --remote-debugging-port=9014  --user-data-dir="Profile 1"

Any idea?

Could you please test the most voted answer from this question here using --user-data-dir and --profile-directory arguments?

Please try without the sandbox option and see if that works

I did some testing and was wrong about adding a binary location. All you have to do is change the os.system to os.startfile like this.
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()      
# os.system('2024\\startchrome_dev.bat')
os.startfile('2024\\startchrome_dev.bat')

options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9014")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


unfortunately I still get selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:9014 from chrome not reachable

Hmm, I get that same error when using os.system, but when I updated it to os.startfile it works and selenium is able to control the window. Have you tested a different port to make sure its open?

yes i've tried with several different ports, still no luck

Hmm, its hard to tell since its working on my end now. The other solutions I've seen include ensuring your chrome version matches the selenium chromedriver version or if your C:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data<Profile>\Preferences file is not to large, if it is delete it and try to run again.

I needed to clone the USER_DATA folder, now it works. thanks

@gaut, try passing the absolute path of the file.
